# Origine e significato dell'espressione "Fare il pesce in barile"

Tags: idioms, etymology, meaning

Durante una discussione ho sentito una persona usare l'espressione **fare il pesce in barile** con riferimento a qualcuno che, se ho ben capito, stava facendo di tutto per tenersi fuori da una situazione spinosa.

Mi sapete dire se è proprio questo il senso della frase? Sarei inoltre curiosa di sapere da dove nasce questa espressione.

Grazie!

Comment: Avevo solo sentito *come sparare ad un pesce in un barile*, che però ha tutt'altro significato...

Comment: Mai sentito! Cosa significa?

Comment: Si dice di qualcosa estremamente facile. L'idea è che "pescare" sparando con un fucile dentro ad un barile pieno di pesci è una cosa facilissima...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fare il pesce in [barile](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/P/pesce.shtml):

> - Mostrare di non vedere e non sentire nulla, di non accorgersi di quello che accade intorno, come non può vedere nulla uno dei tanti pesci tenuti in conserva dentro un barile.
> - rimaner neutrale fra due partiti opposti

L'origine non è' chiara ma è' evidente il riferimento all'attività ittica tipica del nostro paese.

- [Ministro Severino](http://www.felicebelisario.it/2012/04/16/ministro-severo-fa-pesce-in-barile/) fa pesce in barile

(16 aprile 2012 in Comunicati Stampa, Giustizia, Politica e Valori)

> - “Anche il ministro Severino fa il pesce in barile, ma così rischia di restare sepolta dalle indagini in corso che rivelano ogni giorno di più la corruzione devastante che avvolge come un cancro il nostro Paese.

Comment: E' circa quello che avevo capito anche io. Mi dispiace non si riesca a scoprire di più sull'origine! Grazie comunque!